# Query results take too long. Is there a better way to write this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I am trying to `optimize` a `mysql` query that works perfectly but is taking way too long.  My inventory table is nearly **300,000 records** (not too bad).  I am not sure if using a `subquery` or `join` or additional `index` would speed up my results.  I do have the district_id columns indexed in both the students and inventory tables.

Basically, the `query` below pulls all the inventory of all students in a teacher's roster.  So it first has to search the students table to find which students are in the teacher's roster, then has to search the inventory table for each student.  So if a teacher has 30+ students it can be a lot of searches through the inventory and each student can have 30+ pieces of inventory. Any advice would be helpful!

```
SELECT  inventory.inventory_id, items.title, items.isbn, items.item_num,
        items.price, conditions.condition_name, inventory.check_out,
        inventory.check_in, inventory.student_id, inventory.teacher_id
    FROM  inventory, conditions, items, students
    WHERE  students.teacher_id = '$teacher_id'
      AND  students.district_id = $district_id
      AND  inventory.student_id = students.s_number
      AND  inventory.district_id = $district_id
      AND  inventory.item_id = items.item_id
      AND  items.consumable !=1
      AND  conditions.condition_id = inventory.condition_id
    ORDER BY  inventory.student_id, inventory.inventory_id
```

Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `inventory` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `inventory_id` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `item_id` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `district_id` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `condition_id` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `check_out` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `check_in` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `student_id` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `teacher_id` varchar(6) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `acquisition_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `notes` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Check the query execution plan. If you have indexes, verify if those are getting used by the optimizer.

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Should it matter the performance ? I think its just ANSI vs NonANSI.

Comment: Better way is to write the query is to use the JOIN syntax and not the comma syntax... and please provide the `show create table [table]` outputs

Comment: The rule which works most of the time is to create an index on join columns.

Comment: `INDEXes` are your friend; don't leave home without them.

Answer (score 0):

First you rewrite this to use explicit JOINs:

```
SELECT inventory.inventory_id, 
       items.title, items.isbn, items.item_num, items.price, 
       conditions.condition_name,
       inventory.check_out,  inventory.check_in, 
       inventory.student_id, inventory.teacher_id  
FROM inventory
  JOIN conditions ON (conditions.condition_id = inventory.condition_id)
  JOIN items ON (inventory.item_id = items.item_id AND items.consumable != 1)
  JOIN students ON (inventory.student_id = students.s_number) 
WHERE students.teacher_id = '$teacher_id' 
  AND students.district_id = $district_id
  AND inventory.district_id = $district_id 
ORDER BY inventory.student_id, inventory.inventory_id
```

Then you examine the JOINs. For example this:

```
  JOIN items ON (inventory.item_id = items.item_id AND items.consumable != 1)
```

means that the items table needs to be scanned on item_id and consumable, which *might* be a constant. It is always better to not use negative conditions if possible. But at the very least you index items on item_id (unless it's already the primary key, as is likely). If consumable can assume, say, values 0, 1, 2, 3, then you go:

```
  JOIN items ON (inventory.item_id = items.item_id AND items.consumable IN (0, 2, 3))
```

and use CREATE INDEX to add an index on consumable.

You may notice that a few columns from inventory are always used in the other JOINs, and there are also some constant constraints.

So another useful index could be

```
 CREATE INDEX ... ON inventory(district_id, student_id, item_id, condition_id)
```

Another useful index would be

ON students(teacher_id, district_id, student_id, s_number)

which allows immediately restricting the WHERE on the involved students, and retrieve the information required by the JOINs without ever loading the table, just using the index.

Comment: Wow thank you so much LSemi.  This response was so helpful.  I really appreciate you breaking it all down for me.  I understand how to use JOINS so much better now that I have a specific example to work with.  I also found a few more columns to index.  This unwieldy query is definitely running faster.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to InnoDB!  Some of what I am about to say is less efficient in InnoDB.

```
SELECT  i.inventory_id,
        items.title, items.isbn, items.item_num, items.price,
        c.condition_name,
        i.check_out, i.check_in, i.student_id, i.teacher_id
    FROM  inventory AS i
    JOIN  conditions AS c  ON c.condition_id = i.condition_id
    JOIN  items  ON i.item_id = items.item_id
    JOIN  students AS s  ON  i.student_id = s.s_number
    WHERE  s.teacher_id = '$teacher_id'
      AND  s.district_id = $district_id
      AND  i.student_id = s.s_number
      AND  i.district_id = $district_id
      AND  items.consumable != 1
    ORDER BY  i.student_id, i.inventory_id
```

To help the Optimizer if it would like to start with `students`:

```
students: INDEX(district_id, teacher_id, s_number)
```

Note: this is also "covering", thereby avoiding bouncing between index BTree and data BTree.  (What is the PK of `students`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

If consuming the `ORDER BY` is better:

```
inventory: INDEX(district_id, student_id, inventory_id)
```

Also needed:

```
items:      (item_id)       -- probably already the PRIMARY KEY?
conditions: (condition_id)  -- probably already the PRIMARY KEY?
```

Verify or add those 4 indexes.  (The Optimizer will dynamically choose what to do.)